# How to Iterate through an index of n using different index of p

Tags: powershell

I am doing this in PowerShell, although the question isn't tied to a language.

lets say that I have an indexed array of size n called accounts, and another indexed array of size p called rows. I want to go through each of the items in row and use an account to do something. In my real world example, I have excel rows and I need to log into accounts in the accounts array in a round-robin fashion. the size of these arrays can be anything from 1 to n, and they will very likely not be the same size as the other. What math problem can I use to ensure that, regardless of the size of the array, I get the iterations below (assume $rows.Count is 500 and $accounts.Count is 12:

```
rows[1] - accounts[1]
rows[2] - accounts[2]
rows[3] - accounts[3]
rows[4] - accounts[4]
rows[5] - accounts[5]
rows[6] - accounts[6]
rows[7] - accounts[7]
rows[8] - accounts[7]
rows[9] - accounts[8]
rows[10] - accounts[9]
rows[11] - accounts[10]
rows[12] - accounts[11]
rows[13] - accounts[12]
rows[14] - accounts[1]
rows[15] - accounts[2]
rows[16] - accounts[3]
rows[17] - accounts[4]
```

My attempts have landed on this so far:

```
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $rows.Count; $i++) {
    $k = 0
    $j = $accounts.Count
    if ($i -le $j) {
        $k = $j
    }
    else {
        $k = $i % $j
    }
    $rows[$i] - $accounts[$k]
}
```

I think that modulus is the key, but I can't seem to finish the equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, using `%`, the [modulus operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arithmetic_Operators), is key; a PowerShell-idiomatic solution (it simply prints the paired array elements):

```bash
$rows = 1..500
$accounts = 1..12

$i = 0
$rows.ForEach({ '{0} - {1}' -f $_, $accounts[$i++ % $accounts.Count] })
```

Note that array indices in PowerShell / .NET are `0`-based.